# CSS: from liquid to fixed for smaller resolution

Tags: css, css-float, resolution, fixed

The code below is a mini web page with 3 elements:
on the left: a soccer goal + ball image
center: a video
on the right: an image of a mobile phone

Viewing the whole thing in a resolution like mine 1440 x 900, there's no problem, all shows ok.
But when you use a less wide resolution (or you re-size the navigator window to less width), the mobile phone image goes behind the video (or the video on top of it).

To fix this, what I am trying to do is:
when reaching 1280px of width and 830 px of height, which is the limit resolution (less than this, things go wrong) I'm trying to get all the elements fixed (nothing floats anymore), so the scroll bars show, the visitor can use them, and no element gets under nothing.

How can achieve this?? Please give me a hand with it, it's been many hours and I'm going nuts.

My last try: adding to the body tag
min-width:1280px;

But no results :( I'm wondering if this is correctly used and if it could be a solution .. what do you think?

PD: please download the images here:
http://aracelid.110mb.com/myfolder.zip

Thanks a lot

```
<head> 

<style type="text/css"> 
#navigation {
}

#navigation ul, #navigation ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#navigation ul {
    padding: 5px 15px; 
    text-align: left;
}

#navigation ul li {
    display: inline;

    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-top:10px;
}

#navigation ul li a div {
    background: url("myfolder/boton_ROLLOUT_08.png") no-repeat;

    padding: 10px 0.5em;

    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:12px;
}

#navigation ul li a div:hover {
    background: url("myfolder/boton_ROLLOVER_08.png") no-repeat;

    padding: 10px 0.5em;

    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:12px;
}     
</style>

</head> 

<body style="background-color:#E7E7E7;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"> 

<div style="z-index:-1;position:absolute;left:0;top:30%;height:50%;width:100%;float:none">

    <div style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:0px;"><img src="myfolder/goal.jpg"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:-90px;right:0px"><img src="myfolder/sonyx10_06.jpg"></div>

</div>


<div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:20%">
 <div id="navigation" style="z-index:1;position:relative;top:-18px;left:0px"> 
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="#" id="t1" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;" ><div id="t1" style="float:left;width:140px;text-align:center;">tab1&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" id="t2" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;"><div id="t2" style="float:left;width:140px;text-align:center">tab2&nbsp;</div></a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" id="t3" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;"><div id="t3" style="float:left;width:140px;text-align:center">tab3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></a></li> 
    </ul> 

</div>

 <div id="video" style="z-index:50;text-align:left;float:left;width:726px;height:491px;padding:0px;margin-top:-20px">


            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="710" height="480" id="index" align="middle"> 
                <param name="movie" value="http://elandroidelibre.movilgol.mobi/video.swf" /> 
                <param name="quality" value="high" /> 
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /> 
                <param name="play" value="true" /> 
                <param name="loop" value="true" /> 
                <param name="wmode" value="window" /> 
                <param name="scale" value="showall" /> 
                <param name="menu" value="true" /> 
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" /> 
                <param name="salign" value="" /> 
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /> 
                <!--[if !IE]>--> 
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://elandroidelibre.movilgol.mobi/video.swf" width="710" height="480"> 
                    <param name="movie" value="http://elandroidelibre.movilgol.mobi/video.swf" /> 
                    <param name="quality" value="high" /> 
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /> 
                    <param name="play" value="true" /> 
                    <param name="loop" value="true" /> 
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" /> 
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" /> 
                    <param name="menu" value="true" /> 
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" /> 
                    <param name="salign" value="" /> 
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /> 
                <!--<![endif]--> 
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"> 
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Adobe Flash Player" /> 
                    </a> 
                <!--[if !IE]>--> 
                </object> 
                <!--<![endif]--> 
            </object> 


</div>

</div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the containing element a `min-width` and `min-height`. Next time, please strip down your code to the bare minimum.

Some tips

- Don't use style attributes. You want
  to separate your content from the
  presentation. That's why you use CSS.
  Don't mix style back in there.
- Remember: Absolute positioned content
  is positioned against the nearest
  parent element with a positioning
  different from `static`. z-index can
  only be set on elements with a
  positioning different from `static`.

I did some rewriting because it was too big of a mess: (I changed the video to a red pane because it was too distracting :))

```
   <head> 

    <style type="text/css"> 

        body{
            background-color:#E7E7E7;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            position:relative; 
            min-width:1280px;
            min-height:830px;
        }

        #navigation { 
            list-style: none;
            margin: 70px 0px 0px 0px;
            padding: 0;
            text-align:center;
        }

        #navigation li {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #navigation a {
            display: block;
            width: 140px;
            height: 15px;
            background: url("myfolder/boton_ROLLOUT_08.png") no-repeat;
            padding: 10px 0.5em;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:12px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #navigation a:hover {
            background: url("myfolder/boton_ROLLOVER_08.png") no-repeat;
        }

        #container{
            position: relative;
        }

        #goal, #gsm {
            top: 100px;
            position:absolute;
        }

        #goal {
            left:0px;
        }

        #gsm {
            right:0px;
        }

        #video {
            position:relative; z-index: 1;
            width:726px;height:491px;
            background: #F00;
            margin: 0px auto;
        }
    </style>

</head> 

<body> 

    <ul id="navigation"> 
        <li><a href="#" id="t1">tab1&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" id="t2">tab2&nbsp;</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" id="t3">tab3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li> 
    </ul>

    <div id="container">
        <img id="goal" src="myfolder/goal.jpg">
        <img id="gsm" src="myfolder/sonyx10_06.jpg">
        <div id="video"></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

I know it is not perfect but it's the quickest example I could get together and I think there is a lot you can learn from it already.